# LibSVM prediction accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, cross-validation, hyperparameters, forward-testing

I am currently trying to run **`LibSVM`** located here: https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm

I only have access to MATLAB 2011b. When I try to run the example data file (heartscale) included with the `LibSVM` package with different **`C`** and **`gamma`** values I get the same accuracy results.

This happens for other data sets as well.

I build a **`for`** loop and loop through the different `C` and `gamma` values and the accuracy %'s do not change.

I am doing this to find the best `C` and `gamma` to use for the data set (cross-validation) as recommended in the documentation "A Practical Guide to Support Vector Classification" located on the above website.

When I look at the `accuracy_mat` that I build below, the values are all the same. Even the outputs from `svmpredict` are the same.

I have read through the documentation multiple times and looked at the FAQ on the website and would appreciate inputs on this from SVM-practitioners.

```
[heart_scale_label, heart_scale_inst] = libsvmread( 'heartscale' );
C = { '2^-5','2^-3','2^-1'};
g = {'2^-15','2^-3','2^-1'};
accuracy_mat = zeros(  length( g ), length( c ) );
data_num     = length( heart_scale_inst(:,1) );
t            = zeros(  data_num, 1 );
for i = 1:length( g )
    for j = 1:length( C )
        c_train_inputs    = ['-c ', C{j}];
        g_train_inputs    = ['-g ', g{i}];
        c_and_g_inputs    = [c_train_inputs, g_train_inputs];
        model             = svmtrain(   heart_scale_label,          ...
                                        heart_scale_inst,           ...
                                        [c_and_g_inputs, '-b 1']    ...
                                        );
        [predict_label, ...
         accuracy,      ...
         prob_estimates]  = svmpredict( heart_scale_label,          ...
                                        heart_scale_inst,           ...
                                        model,                      ...
                                        '-b 1'                      ...
                                        );
        accuracy_mat(i,j) = max( accuracy );
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Initial range for `[C,gamma]` hyper-parameters locked you in a corner

Support Vector methods are very powerful engines.

Still, one may still destroy their cool predictive powers, either by a poor data-sanitization ( regularisation, NaN removal etc. ) or by sending an order to use a corner-case hyperparameter(s) `C` or `gamma`.

Before a SVM/SVC engines are put into hard work, the more if a brute-force hyper-parameter space search is planned to be run ( `GridSearchCV` et al ), where CPUs/GPUs may easily spend more than hundreds of hours, a simple rule of thumb ought to be use for a pre-validation of the search-space.

[Andreas Mueller has put that nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26346545/3666197) to first scan SVM `rbf`'s ( while the pre-scan idea is valid in general, not only for an `rbf` model ) over a "rule-of-thumb" range of values:

```
{'C': np.logspace(-3, 2, 6), 'gamma': np.logspace(-3, 2, 6)}
```

i.e. unless you are pretty sure ( or forbidden by some untold restriction )
to use just your ultra-low learning parametrisation values preset in `[ C, gamma ]`- search space, you might allow to relax the range so as to allow the SVM-learner progress to some other results farther from the observed corner it has got locked so far.

```
C = { 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0 }
g = { 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0 }
```

If you do not see any evolution of the SVM-learner results over this sand-box pre-test landscape of it's hyper-parameters, than the root cause would be hidden in `DataSET` ( which does not seem to be the case, as you posted an observation, that the same trouble appeared independently of one particular DataSET under review ).

**Nota bene:** one might also rather test descriptive statistical values about the trained model:

```
model_predictions_accuracy_mean(i,j) = mean( accuracy );
model_predictions_accuracy_var( i,j) = var(  accuracy );

accuracy_mat(                   i,j) = max(  accuracy ); %% MAX masks
                                                         %% quality-of-fit
                                                         %% & may "look" same
                                                         %%   for the whole range
```